# How to output arrays horizontally in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, io, delimiter

Hello I'm using a console program in c++ that uses I/O to read in a textfile and output the average of the numbers in the textfile. However when the numbers print out they are displayed vertically in the output file. Is there a delimitor in c++ to output my array horizontally?

Here is what I am outputting:

```
 for( i = 1; i < 10; i++)
  {
      inFile >> retrievenum[i];

      sum += retrievenum[i];
 //Here I'm outputting the array to my output textfile
      outFile <<retrievenum[i] << endl;

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use a tab to separate your output.  Tab is represented by the character `'\t'`.

```
for( i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    inFile >> retrievenum[i];

    sum += retrievenum[i];
    //Here I'm outputting the array to my output textfile
    outFile <<retrievenum[i] << '\t';
}

//  outFile << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use << endl until after your for loop.

Endl indicates that you want to end the line and flush the buffer.  In this case that is not what you want to do.  You can output any delimiter you want in place of the endl, or do nothing and let them run together.

If you have a long operation inside the loop, you may want to flush the buffer without an end line after each output [`std::flush;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush)

Answer (score 1):

`std::endl` is similar to the `\n` character.  It ends the current line and any future output will be on the next line.  Taking `endl` out will keep your output all on one line.  You can replace it with a few different things.

```
'\t'    //put a tab between each output
" "     //put a space between each output
", "    //put a comma and space between each output, etc.
```

Comment: Not quite the same.  \n only inserts a new line, it does not flush the buffer.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/endl/?kw=endl  http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/7350/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a loop:

```
std::copy(retrievenum, retrievenum + 10, std::ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Or for all 3 of your operations:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(inFile), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(vec));
sum = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0);
std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: When you are used to using the provided algorithms, it is pretty straight-forward.  Declare a vector of ints, Copy from a stream into the vector of ints, sum up the values of the vector of ints, copy the vector of ints to the a stream, spit out an end of line/flush.

Answer (score 1):

Well just remove the endl from your cout and replace it with a white space, this will make the output more readable and it will print horizontally.